# vba macro to create .txt list of filepaths

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro to list out all the files in subfolders of a particular folder. what I want to do is create a .txt file in the main folder that has a list of all the filepaths? Basically a macro to create a txt file which lists column A of my excel spreadsheet. I know this is easy to do without vba(you just save as a text file) but i need to find a way to automate it?!

Comment: [See this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/664194-visual-basic-applications-save-specific-sheet-work-book-txt-file.html) if you just want to save any worksheet as .txt file

Comment: please post the code that you have attempted to get this to work and we can help you fix what may not be working

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the data in column **A** then:

```
Sub MkFile()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Close #1
    Open "C:\TestFolder\TestFile.txt" For Output As #1
    For i = 1 To N
      Print #1, Cells(i, "A").Value
    Next i
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Change the folder or file names to suit your needs.